# Woocommerce: add functionality to close "add to cart" success message popup

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This is my first post, so please be gentle. I'm finishing up a Woocommerce-based site, and my clients have requested that there be the ability to close (e.g. with a little "x" button) the little popup banner for the "successfully added to cart" message that appears on product pages. (Currently there only exists the option to "view cart" via that popup.) This does not appear to be a built-in setting for this in WooCommerce.

To see what I'm talking about, you can go to https://www.drinkreorient.com/product/rose-root/ and add this product to the cart (no purchase necessary ;-)). You should then see the popup.

I've made a few attempts at it via googling around and fiddling with functions.php and the "wc_add_to_cart_message" function, but no success. I'm not terribly fluent in the php (or javascript) necessary to make this happen. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't really need to mess with the `wc_add_to_cart_message`. Instead, you should override the [`woocommerce/templates/notices/success.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/notices/success.php) template, and modify it to suit your needs by adding a close button, along with some javascript to perform that action.

First, to override the template, you should follow the instructions found in the documentation for [Template Structure](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/), specifically:

> Copy it into a directory within your theme named /woocommerce, keeping the same file structure but removing the /templates/ subdirectory.

Once you've copied this `[your-theme]/woocommerce/notices/success.php` file into place, something like this should be fairly close to what you're looking for:

```
<?php
/* Modified version of [your-theme]/woocommerce/notices/success.php */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

if ( ! $messages ){
    return;
}
?>
<style>
    .woocommerce-message .close-button {
        /* customize the close button */
        float:right;
        display:inline-block;
        color:white;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
</style>
<script>
  (function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.woocommerce-message .close-button').on('click', function(){
        $('.woocommerce-message').fadeOut(function(){$(this).remove();});
      });
    });
  }(jQuery));
</script>
<?php foreach ( $messages as $message ) : ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-message">
        <?php echo wp_kses_post( $message ); ?>    
        <span class="close-button">X</span>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Those two steps should get you exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: This did exactly what I needed, thanks. I appreciate you providing the full solution, from start to finish!

Comment: Glad to hear! If you don't mind, please accept my response as the best answer. Thanks!

Comment: An interesting side effect. This template is used on the cart page for messages but.... (it's a big one) the javascript is removed for some reason.

I can find no reference to this anywhere. Help!

Comment: I used this, and it worked in the shop, but in cart page the button works only the first time on the page. if I edit the cart product qty after That, the X button doesn't work, why? :(

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar request from a client.
but instead of an "x" to close the pop up it was to make it fade after x number of seconds.

see the see this link: http://ausauraair.com.au/product/ausaura-air/

by adding some jQuery i was able to make the box fade.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
$('.woocommerce-message').fadeTo(7000,1).fadeOut(2000);
});
```

you could possibly use a similar technique but add a "x" button and then an on-click function to make the box close on click.

Comment: Very cool, thank you. Had not considered fading out; will run this past the client to see if that's an even better solution for them.

Comment: It's possible, and quite cool, to do both. But see my comment to the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Additional of [Christian Caltabiano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7272205/christian-caltabiano) code , this could be more useful to delay messages few seconds...

```
<script>jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {  $('.woocommerce-message').fadeTo(300,1).delay(3000).fadeOut(300);   }); </script>
```

```js
$('#go').click(function(){
$('#para').fadeOut().delay(3000).fadeIn();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input id="go" type="button" value="Go" /></p>
<p id="para">This text will fade out and pause</p>
```